# set video as favorite in youtube data api v3

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I want to set video as favorite it can be done by [this method](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.insert). But What will be playlistid for favorite.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to list channels with params like these: (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

part = contentDetails
mine = true

You'll receive channel info with section like this

```
"contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
        "likes": "#playlistID#",
        "favorites": "#playlistID#",
        "uploads": "#playlistID#",
        "watchHistory": "#playlistID#",
        "watchLater": "#playlistID#"
    },
    "googlePlusUserId": "..."
}
```

and you can use these ids for different manipulations with playlists